# Option "bevelOffset" has no impact on my Extrude Geometry

Tags: three.js

I've been looking for a means to render roof-like shapes with three.js, and I am trying to do so with the "bevel" properties of the ExtrudeBufferGeometry. In [this example](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeBufferGeometry) it looked like the property "bevelOffset" was doing exactly what I was looking for to complete my roof shapes. But when I tried on my scripts, it.. didn't change anything to the geometry. So I built an almost minimal code to test it and it didn't work either. I also checked the spelling but it continued to be "ignored"... what's wrong ?

```js
var camera, SCENE, renderer, SUN;

init();

function init() {
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
 camera.position.set(0,10,-10);

 SCENE = new THREE.Scene();

 SUN = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.6 );
 SCENE.add( SUN );

 SCENE.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.8 ) );

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
 renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

 var shape = new THREE.Shape();
 shape.moveTo( 0,0 );
 shape.lineTo( 0, 5 );
 shape.lineTo( 5, 5 );
 shape.lineTo( 5, 0 );
 shape.lineTo( 0, 0 );
 var extrudeSettings = {steps:1,depth:5,bevelEnabled:true,bevelOffset:1,bevelSize:1,bevelThickness:1,bevelSegments:1};
 var geo = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(shape,extrudeSettings)
 var obj = new THREE.Mesh( geo ,[new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"blue"}),new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"yellow"})]);
 SCENE.add( obj );

 camera.position.set(obj.position.x-8,10,obj.position.z-10);
 camera.lookAt(obj.position);
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 SUN.target = obj;

 renderer.render( SCENE, camera );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.min.js"></script>
```

I tried multiple values for bevelOffset in this example but nothing changed. Could you try yourself ?

Comment: Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/euhn7m0g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the last version of three.js and it worked; I should have done this before, thank you !